# What is the meaning of "ClassInstance.[Someclass::class.java]" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've seen people using ViewModelProvider[Someclass::class.java] instead of ViewModelProvider.get(Someclass::class.java), and it compiles in Android Studio. The problem is that I couldn't find any documentation of such usage online.
[image: example]

Comment: there must be an operation overloading for `[]` operator somewhere, I couldn't find it :D

Comment: @moshen It's automatic for Java classes with the matching name of an operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With kotlin you can add operator modifiers to your function. So if you have some class with a `get` function and you might want to access it with `[]`, like an array or map, you could add `operator` modifier.

> Square brackets are translated to calls to get and set with appropriate numbers of arguments.

So this only works for functions with name `get` or `set`!

```kotlin
class Provider {
  operator fun get(key: String)
  operator fun set(key: String, value: String) { ... }
}
```

Then you can call the function like:

```kotlin
Provider().get("key") // IDE hint: should be replaced with indexing operator
Provider()["key"] // calls get()

Provider().set("key", "value") // IDE hint: should be replaced with indexing operator
Provider()["key"] = "value" // calls set()
```

**Reference**

- See [Kotlin Operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin allows operator overloading by marking a function as an `operator` function. The square brackets notation is one of these operators ([indexed access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed)).

Kotlin automatically interprets Java functions as operator functions [if their name and signature match the requirements of a Kotlin operator function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#operators). In this case, it interprets functions named `get` as an "indexed access operator" if they return something, which allows you to use square bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModelProvider[Someclass::class.java]` is a shorter version of `ViewModelProvider.get(Someclass::class.java)` there is no differences.